# How to force @media print for automated test?

Tags: css, testing, media-queries, automated-tests, protractor

From bootstrap, I am using `hidden-print` to hide certain things when printed.  I want to write an automated test to verify this.  I don't know how to force the browser so that `@media print` media queries will fire.

Currently we are using protractor for this kind of testing, but if anyone can provide any solution with another tool, that would be a great starting point.

Comment: I suspect there would be a way to automate some local DOM manipulation to swap `media="print"` to `media="all"`. Depends what the testing suite you're using is capable of I suppose. If you can run some JS on the page before testing, that would do it.

Comment: Check that out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46088732/how-to-test-media-print-with-protractor-or-selenium/46129207#46129207