# How to test @media print with protractor or selenium?

Tags: css, selenium, protractor, automated-tests

I've implemented an print functionallity at my site, and I would like to test it via protractor / selenium.

There is any method to "apply" the styles that are under `@media print` during the test?

I saw only one relevant [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33416998/how-to-force-media-print-for-automated-test), but it without any good answer.

For example at that sample I would like to the `#hidden` div will be shown during the test.

```css
.print-only {
  display: none;
}

@media print {
  .print-only {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="hidden" class="print-only">Will be shown when printing</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One option that I've found is to split all the "print" css into a separate file, and load it via `link` tag with `media="print"`.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print">
```

Meaning not to use `media query` inside large css file at all.

That way will allow me to change the `media="print"` attribute during test to `all` via `executeScript`.

Hope it will help someone.